# How to forward all email messages under a particular label in Gmail to another person?

Tags: gmail

Does anyone know how to forward all email messages under a particular label in Gmail to another person?

I have 105 email messages that I managed under the label "Stumble Upon" and now I want to send all of them to another person. Is this possible?

Answer (score 9):

**Solution for future incoming e-mails**

Create a new filter with the adequate words or label and then apply the filter.

Here it is step by step:

- Go to Settings (button top right of your inbox)
- Pick the `Filters` tab
- At the very bottom, click on `Create a new filter`
- In the field `Has the words`, add "label:StumbleUpon" (or whatever)
- Choose `Create filter with this search`
- Check `Forward it to:` and choose the right e-mail address
- Check `Apply to the [XX] conversations`
- Press `Create Filter`

[EDIT] The "Apply" doesn't work for old mails, you will have to use one of these tricks:

**Forwarding past mails**

- Either use [IMAP](http://ask.metafilter.com/205496/How-to-bulk-forward-old-messages-from-one-gmail-account-to-another)
- Or [command line](https://github.com/jay0lee/got-your-back/wiki)

Comment: The command line solution Got Your Back mentioned above is really powerful. New link is here: https://github.com/jay0lee/got-your-back/wiki

Comment: it already doesn't work in 2021

Answer (score 2):

You can use Google Scripts to [Forward Gmail messages in bulk](http://www.labnol.org/internet/auto-forward-gmail-messages/20665/) based on labels and unlike filters, scripts even work with existing messages.

Comment: Please add the instructions to the answer instead of just linking to your own site. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SquadMail](https://www.squadmail.com/) and share that label with someone. Just sing up for free, create a label and invite someone else to it. The label will show up in both of your Gmail accounts and every email you put in it is automatically synchronized.